# releasing a NSURLConnection?

Tags: objective-c

I have a connection to server , and i want to release its `queue`, i don't now how.

```
     [NSURLConnection
         sendAsynchronousRequest:request
         queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
         completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                             NSData *data,
                             NSError *error)

//some if else statements

   }];
```

i dont get how to `release` this queue argument between 2 connections ?

Comment: Do you want to release the NSURLConnection, or the NSOperationQueue? Are you using ARC?

Comment: I am taking a guess at `[[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease]` don't hold me to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ARC, you do not have to do anything.

If not, you can include `autorelease`.